# Add an SSH option to an sftp URL in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, ssh, sftp

I'm connecting to a remote server in Nautilus using an URL of the form *sftp://server.com*. However, due to a thing with that server I need to add an option when connecting via SSH, otherwise the login is very, very slow:

```
ssh -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no server.com
```

Is there a way to use this option in Nautilus with SFTP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create `~/.ssh/config` with an appropriate config entry for your host like so:

```
Protocol 2
Host yourhost
    User youruser
    Hostname your.host.address
    GSSAPIAuthentication no
    Port 1234
```

For more options, consult `man ssh_config`

Comment: This works when the hostname is some fixed domain or IP, but is there a solution when this isn't known beforehand?

Comment: To make it a default setting, just put it into the same file but before any ``Host`` statements.